# Errors with LSTM input shapes with time series data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to predict torque from 8 features with an LSTM layer in my neural network. I'm having trouble with the input shape and have looked around on many sites for a solution. I'm quite new to machine learning and am having trouble understanding the problem and how I can fix this. Here is my code, dataset, and error message.

```
file = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/only_force_pt1.csv'


df = pd.read_csv(file)

X = df.iloc[:, 1:9]
y = df.iloc[:,9]
print(X)
print(y)
df.head()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, shuffle = True)

[verbose, epochs, batch_size] = [1, 200, 32]
input_shape = (X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1])

model = Sequential()

# LSTM
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences = True))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience = 20, verbose =1, mode = 'auto')

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])



history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, verbose = verbose, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), callbacks = [earlystopper])
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3634, 8), found shape=(None, 8)
```

dataset: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQOXffFYioCiPug2VcBZEZVD-u3y9bcl?usp=sharing][1]](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQOXffFYioCiPug2VcBZEZVD-u3y9bcl?usp=sharing%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, I think that you are passing the number of data points as an additional dimension on the input shape of the LSTM layer. Your data dimensionality is 8 and 3634(`=X_train.shape[0]`) is the number of data points, which should match the first dimension (with `None`) of the input tensors, and should *not* be passed as a dimension to the LSTM because it is determined by the batch size.

If that's the case, change the `input_shape` definition to:

```
input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],)
```

and it should work.